# Buffer overflow: bypass input string formatting

Tags: c, linux, buffer-overflow, format-string

I'm trying to solve an exercise on buffer overflow and format string bugs. The vulnerable function is:

```
scanf("%s",buffer);
```

However, in this way, it is not possible to overwrite the target address with a valid memory address.
In fact, whatever I input, the string formatter **%s** converts it in the corresponding hex (including hexadecimals themselves).
How can I bypass it and overwrite the target address with a valid memory address?

Comment: You can't overwrite the target address. You can write to the buffer where it points, say `"ABCD"` which is hexadecimal bytes `41 42 43 44` which is the 32-bit (little-endian) value `0x44434241`. The point about buffer overflow is you can overwrite another address that you should not (say the return address from a function), and get control of execution.

Comment: Yes, but if, for example, I input `\xa0\x0d\xe5\xf7` the placeholder **%s** will convert it into the corresponding hex `5c7861305c7830645c7865355c786637` (due to the fact that it formats the input as a string and not as an hexadecimal). That's the problem.

Comment: The string has to contain the actual values, not escaped values, similar to what I showed. You *can't* include the value `0d` that you show, because it is a "whitespace" character that terminates the string input. The escaped values are what the compiler understands when building code and have nothing to do with string input.

Comment: Yes, but assuming that I have to input the following address `\xff\xff\xff\xff`, which does not contain any escape value, It will be converted into `5c7866665c7866665c7866665c786666`, so the problem remains.

Comment: You are entering \ then `x` then `f` then `f` and so on. They are just 4 charcters that have no connection with each other. In *source code* given to a compiler `\xff` is an escape code, telling the compiler to use the character with value `ff` (which you can't type as text into the source code). But `scanf` does not understand escape codes and all it sees is those 4 unconnected characters.

Comment: Note too that `scanf` isn't converting anything to hexadecimal. That happens earlier, in the keyboard handler. You press a key with `A` on it and the keyboard sends the key number to the handler which replaces the key number with the character code mapped to it, which here would be `0x41`. That's happened before the value arrives at `scanf`.